# Presto, how to duplicate a record based on a time validity interval

Tags: etl, presto

I'm traying to make the below transformation in presto:

From:

```
id | valid_from | valid_unitl | value
12 | 2021/02/17 | 2021/05/17  | 150
```

To:

```
id | date       | value
12 | 2021/02/17 | 150    
12 | 2021/03/17 | 150    
12 | 2021/04/17 | 150
12 | 2021/05/17 | 150
```

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sequence` function to generate an array between `valid_from` and `valid_until` with the desired step and then `unnest` it:

```
select id, format_datetime(date,'yyyy/MM/dd') as date, value 
from my_table 
cross join unnest(sequence(parse_datetime(valid_from,'yyyy/MM/dd'),
                           parse_datetime(valid_until,'yyyy/MM/dd'),
                           interval '1' month)) t(date)
```

See the docs for the `sequence` function: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html